# Read quoted array elements with spaces from file?

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

I'm passing data from `STDIN` into an array using `read` like so:

```
prompt$ cat myfile
a "bc" "d e" f
prompt$ read -a arr < myfile
```

But `read` doesn't appear to pay attention to the quoted strings and provides me an array of 5 elements:

```
prompt$ echo ${#arr[@]}
5
prompt$ echo ${arr[@]:0}
a "bc" "d e" f
prompt$ echo ${arr[2]}
"d
prompt$ echo ${arr[3]}
e"
```

I'm using the default `IFS` setting: `\t\n` in `bash`.
There are several ways to accomplish task using different tools, but I'm surprised that read doesn't support quoted strings.

Any other suggestions for getting a delimited list with quotes into an array?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't think of a very good way to do what you are asking for, but,
if you know that your input file is going to contain space-separated
tokens that are valid syntax for bash, then something like the
following could work:

```
declare -a arr="($(<myfile))"
```

Comment: Thank you for mentioning `declare`. I'm hesitant to use `eval` much, but it seems that `cat myfile | { while read -r; do declare -a "arr=($REPLY)"; done}` will get the job done.

Comment: At the heart of it, `declare -a "arr=($MYVAR)"` will do the same with a variable.

Comment: 1_CR: Wow, yes, this makes the command a lot less horrible. I will integrate this into my answer.

Comment: @Mr.Dave I'm not sure if by your comment you mean you're glad to have found an alternative to `eval` or realized that this is actually equivalent to `eval`. Anyway, I just checked because I wasn't sure and I was hoping it'd be limited to array syntax, but found that it does indeed `eval` any bash code that goes into that string. I'm putting this comment as a warning to others that might hope as I did.

Comment: @JoL 1,000+ days later, I'm not sure what I meant either. Sorry.

Answer (score 5):

Use this:

```
IFS=$'\n' arr=( $(xargs -n1 <file) )
```

- `IFS=$'\n'` sets bashs internal field separator to newline.
- `arr=( ... )` the array definition.
- `xargs -n1 <file` `xargs` reads the `file` with a maximum of 1 argument. The string in quotes stay together, because they are read as arguments.

The output (one element per line):

```
$ printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}"
a
bc
d e
f
```

Comment: Nice, I hadn't thought of using xargs, which does respect quotes.

Comment: @dhag xargs can be used by more cases than just to build commands from stdin =)